# C++ chars stored in the LPCSTR .. broken?

Tags: c++, string, variables, lpcstr

```
LPCSTR dllPath = ExePath().append("\\").append(DEF_INJECT_DLL).c_str();
DWORD dwBufSize = (DWORD)(strlen(dllPath) + 1) * sizeof(LPCSTR);

/* test */

char tbuf[1024]= {0,};
sprintf_s(tbuf, "dllPath : %s\r\ndwBufSize : %d", dllPath, dwBufSize);
MessageBoxA(NULL, tbuf, "TEST", MB_OK);
```

part of the code to inject my dll.

`ExePath()` is a function to get `AbsolutePath` of `std::string` data type using `GetModuleFileNameA` API and so on.

`DEF_INJECT_DLL` is defined by `#define "MyDll.dll"`

But when I run this code, it shows me broken strings....

[image]

And, when I change the `MessageBoxA` to this:

```
MessageBoxA(NULL,
            ExePath().append("\\").append(DEF_INJECT_DLL).c_str(),
            "TEST",
            MB_OK);
```

[image]

it shows properly?

Also, I tried in this way:

```
MessageBoxA(NULL,dllPath, "TEST", MB_OK);
```

but it shows to me like first screenshot.

What is the problem?

Comment: I'd guess it's some problem with wide character representations. You should try `std::wstring`.

Comment: You cannot take the address of a temporary, and expect it to remain valid.

Comment: Also, you're multiplying the buffer size by the size of a pointer - which is wrong.  You need to multiply by the size of a character.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in this line:

```
LPCSTR dllPath = ExePath().append("\\").append(DEF_INJECT_DLL).c_str();
```

here you call `ExePath()`, which returns a `std::string` instance, modify it, and finally call `c_str()` to get the raw data buffer.

However, the return value is a temporary object. After that line, the returned `std::string` is deleted, and will clean its memory. Therefore, the address where `dllPath` points to is no longer valid!

You could store the return value in a local instance, e.g.

```
std::string str = ExePath().append("\\").append(DEF_INJECT_DLL);
LPCSTR dllPath = str.c_str();
```